CGS unit of heat calorie or erg?
Heat is one kind of energy. As the cgs unit of energy is erg, so the cgs unit of heat also be erg. But in book, it show that the cgs unit of heat is calorie. please explain..

This should be seen as a historic accident: The calorie is a convenient unit of heat for calorimetric measurements (which doesn't require precise knowledge of the mechanic equivalent), so it was added to the CGS even though CGS already has the erg as unit of energy – it was even used in parallel with SI units (and still is in some areas, such as for food energy).
Wikipedia has an overview of the history of the unit.
As a warning: The usage of the unit calorie is quite inconsistent, sometimes it means about $4.18\,\mathrm{J}$ ("small calorie"), and sometimes $4.18\,\mathrm{kJ}$ ("large calorie"). The unit standardized with CGS was the small calorie. E.g. when discussing nutrition it is common to use the large unit (at least informally in the spoken language).
Note, that it is still quite common to use application specific units in cases where those units can be reproducible measured with high precision, but the conversion to the standard units can't be done with the same precision. E.g. there was a   conventional Ohm based on the quantum Hall effect – this only changed when the units were redefined to be based on fixed values of the fundamental constants (which made the quantum Hall measurement into a standard for the exact SI-Ohm; but changed the value slightly with respect to the previous conventional Ohm).

Although the food ‘calorie’ is a kilocalorie just to make it confusing (at least in the US)…

In Germany it is also really bad: We write kcal on food labels and so on, but people say "Kalorie" to mean that unit when talking about nutrition (and if the unit is used in physics it means about 4.18J).
